# Can I generate allure report show in jenkins by testng?

Tags: jenkins, testng, allure

I can get the expected allure report by "allure serve" or "allure serve allure-results" .
But when i want it deploy in jenkins, comes the problem. the report is nan... and the jenkins console show the command is "allure generate allure-results -c -o allure-report-path"..
Has anyone encounter the same question?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem , it doesn't matters about the command, after i read the allure --help carefully. Of course allure generate ./allure-results -o ./allure-reports, the allure report shows in "allure-reports"!!